# jQuery Mobile blackberry cordova default page

Tags: jquery-mobile, blackberry-jde

I have one index.html page with jQuery mobile pages. The android app in eclipse starts the 1st default page correctly. When I add the index.html page in the blackberry www folder no page is loaded. Do I have to do something special for blackberry ?